# NLTK regex results in wrong pos_tag output for date and currency

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm trying to pos_tag the following text:

```
text = """5.1 Basic Wage:

£350.00 per week payable by monthly instalments in arrear
from 18.12.2015 to 30.06.2016

£550.00 per week payable by monthly instalments in arrear
from 01.07.2016 to 30.06.2017
£650.00 per week payable by monthly instalments in arrear
from 01.07.2017 to 30.06.2018
and £25 from 12.07.2016 to 18th December 2016"""
```

The problem seems to be that part of the date are either tagged as `$` and as `VB` i.e. `(18.', '$'), (u'12.2015', 'CD')` or `(u' 30.', 'VB'), (u'06.2018', 'CD')` instead of `(u'18.12.2015', CD)`, whilst the actual currency `450.00, 650.00` is picked up as only `CD`, What I have so far for the regex is

```
 sentence_re = r'''(?x)(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:.[A-Z])+.?)
                      | (?:\$?\d+(?:.\d+)?%?)
                      | (?:\w+(?:-\w+)*)
                      | (?:...|)(?:[][.,;"\'?():-_`]) 
                   '''
toks = nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, sentence_re)

postoks = nltk.tag.pos_tag(toks)
print postoks
```

For the life of me I can't seem to be able to make any headway with this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the output of `toks` as expected?  Cause from what I observe the tokenization needs fixing.

Comment: Try [`(?x)(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:\.[A-Z])+\.?)|(?:[£$]?\d+(?:\.\d+)*%?)|(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*)|(?:\.{3}|[][.,;\"\'?():_\`-])`](https://regex101.com/r/DsTVhr/1). I suspect you missed to escape the dots, and the main fix here is the replacement of `?` with `*` for `(?:\.\d+)` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/DsTVhr/1):

```
(?x)(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:\.[A-Z])+\.?)
| (?:[£$]?\d+(?:\.\d+)*%?)
| (?:\w+(?:-\w+)*)
| (?:\.{3}|[][.,;\"\'?():_`-])
```

Notes:

- All dots outside of character classes seem to match literal dots and thus must be escaped
- The currency symbols char class is extended as `[£$]` (you can add more there)
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` is turned into `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` and now this will match substrings like `12.34.56`
- The last `...` is supposed to match dots, so, it is turned into `\.{3}` and alternated with the punctuation character class, where the hyphen is placed *at the end* so as not to create a range and match a literal hyphen.